# Failed to create the task hub: DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.DurableTaskStorageException

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have migrated my Azure functions project from .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.1. So, I have also updated other nuget packages to support .Net Core 3.1. After that, when I run my functions project it loads all the functions and after loading it fails continuously with below error.

```
General error: Failed to create the task hub: DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.DurableTaskStorageException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected.
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.222Z] ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected.
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.225Z] ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected.
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.226Z] at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [2022-03-28T14:37:38.228Z] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions.WriteToAsync[T](Stream stream, Stream toStream, IBufferManager bufferManager, Nullable1 copyLength, Nullable1 maxLength, Boolean calculateMd5, ExecutionState1 executionState, StreamDescriptor streamCopyState, CancellationToken token)
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.230Z] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token) [2022-03-28T14:37:38.232Z] --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [2022-03-28T14:37:38.233Z] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsyncInternal[T](RESTCommand1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.235Z] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(Stream target, Nullable1 offset, Nullable1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, IProgress1 progressHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [2022-03-28T14:37:38.237Z] at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync(Encoding encoding, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext, IProgress1 progressHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.241Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.TimeoutHandler.ExecuteWithTimeout[T](String operationName, String account, AzureStorageOrchestrationServiceSettings settings, Func3 operation, AzureStorageOrchestrationServiceStats stats, String clientRequestId) [2022-03-28T14:37:38.243Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.AzureStorageClient.MakeStorageRequest[T](Func3 storageRequest, String accountName, String operationName, String clientRequestId) in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Storage/AzureStorageClient.cs:line 133
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.245Z] Request Information
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.246Z] RequestID:e48ed975-d669-4f3e-a24e-bee26fe21569
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.248Z] RequestDate:Mon, 28 Mar 2022 10:37:33 GMT
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.249Z] StatusMessage:InternalServerError
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.250Z] ErrorCode:
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.252Z]
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.253Z] --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.256Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.AzureStorageClient.MakeStorageRequest[T](Func`3 storageRequest, String accountName, String operationName, String clientRequestId) in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Storage/AzureStorageClient.cs:line 137
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.258Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Storage.Blob.DownloadTextAsync() in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Storage/Blob.cs:line 91
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.260Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Partitioning.BlobLeaseManager.GetTaskHubInfoAsync() in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Partitioning/BlobLeaseManager.cs:line 315
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.262Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Partitioning.BlobLeaseManager.GetOrCreateTaskHubInfoAsync(TaskHubInfo newTaskHubInfo, Boolean checkIfStale) in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Partitioning/BlobLeaseManager.cs:line 266
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.263Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.Partitioning.BlobLeaseManager.CreateLeaseStoreIfNotExistsAsync(TaskHubInfo eventHubInfo, Boolean checkIfStale) in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/Partitioning/BlobLeaseManager.cs:line 70
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.265Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.AzureStorageOrchestrationService.GetTaskHubCreatorTask() in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/AzureStorageOrchestrationService.cs:line 308
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.267Z] at DurableTask.AzureStorage.AzureStorageOrchestrationService.EnsureTaskHubAsync() in //src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/AzureStorageOrchestrationService.cs:line 285
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.425Z] Starting task hub worker. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: CdpRefreshHub. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.6.1. SequenceNumber: 1.
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.441Z] The listener for function 'ExecuteGetCommissioningAsync' was unable to start.
[2022-03-28T14:37:38.443Z] The listener for function 'ExecuteGetCommissioningAsync' was unable to start. DurableTask.AzureStorage: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected. System.Net.Http: The response ended prematurely, with at least 93 additional bytes expected.
[2022-03-28T14:37:40.458Z] Retrying to start listener for function 'ExecuteGetCommissioningAsync' (Attempt 1)
```

.csproj file (Before)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common1" Version="1.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Common2" Version="3.12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

.csproj file(after)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common1" Version="1.0.33.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Common2" Version="3.12.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Share your `.csproj` code to see what packages you have installed in .NET Core 2.2 Functions Project to match the appropriate version of those NuGet Packages in .NET Core 3.3!

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with the packages before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created .NET Core 2.2 Azure Functions Project (Http Trigger) and added the same NuGet Packages along with the same versions provided.

And migrated to .NET Core 3.1 with the same NuGet versioned Packages provided but in the `local.settings.json` file, replaced the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value from local storage to Azure Storage Account Connection String.

> With the local storage emulator (`"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`), it didn't work.

I believe that the error is due to storage connection string mismatch from the given error details.

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem for the first time today. Solved easily by using the VSCode Durable Functions Monitor extension to delete the task hub. Next run from VS will recreate the hub.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS-2022. This issue was resolved using following steps.

1. Run Azurite, in local machine, using below command

   `azurite --silent --location c:\azurite --debug c:\azurite\debug.log`
2. In local.settings.json, use below code:

   `"Values": {`

   `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"}`
3. (optional), start the emulator and check that there is no error

That's it!

Comment: This works as a workaround. This is not a solution; must be a bug in Visual Studio or something

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error is pointing to a container that does not exists.

Fixing the path did work for me.